# when i search name using button click event and http_get in angualar js my form data is auto post

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

js: this is my angular js code ,my angular js code is successfully running but my form value is auto post when button event click.

```
$scope.toggle = function() {

    if ($scope.id_value != null && $scope.id_value != '') {
        $scope.loading = true;

        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:78/Attendence_App/home/get_data/' + $scope.id_value;
        var result = $http.get(url);
        result.success(function(response) {
            $scope.name_value = response;
            $scope.val_show = false;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
        result.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
        });


    } else {
        alert("ID can not be empty");
        $scope.val_show = true;
    }
};
```

this is my html code :

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>home/post_value" method="POST">
   <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
      <tr>
         <td>Date</td>
         <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>ID</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="id_value" id="id" /></td>
         <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="toggle()">Search</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="loading">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td colspan="2">
            <div class=""><img src="http://27.147.128.98/itopupprod3/Image/ajax-loader.GIF" id="loading" alt="loading" /></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-hide="val_show">
         <td>
            Name
         </td>
         <td colspan="2">
            <div>
               <label id="name" ng-bind="name_value"></label>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Attendance Type </td>
         <td colspan="2">
            <label>
            <input type="radio"  name="optionsRadios"  value="Yes">
            Yes
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="No">
            No
            </label>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            Login Time
         </td>
         <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            Logout Time
         </td>
         <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td  class="text-align" colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Info " class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

my form data is auto post when search button click,please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, You have to use ng-submit (while `submit` is your submit function):

`<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  ..... fields, labels, yada yada yada...
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`

for more information, go to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit